# How To Debug NoAvailableAdapter for Nannou with Debian running Gnome xOrg?

Tags: rust, debian, gnome

I tried setting up Nannou [following the instructions here](https://guide.nannou.cc/getting_started/platform-specific_setup.html).

I am running Debian Buster on a MacBook with an NVIDIA graphics card (GK107M [GeForce GT 750M Mac Edition]).

I tried running the example and get the error

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'could not build default app window: NoAvailableAdapter'
```

It seems this is an error when Nannou tries to open a window -- something about its communication with the window manager (Gnome on xOrg), or something about vulcan-tools.

Any ideas for how to debug this?

Comment: [Does this solve your problem?](https://github.com/nannou-org/nannou/issues/653#issuecomment-687066157)

Comment: hi @pretzelhammer, thanks for link, but did not solve my problem.

I've now also identified if I run 'vulcaninfo' in terminal, I get  this error:

`/build/vulkan-tools-6bmpQy/vulkan-tools-1.1.97+dfsg1/vulkaninfo/vulkaninfo.c:3845: failed with VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED`

so I suspect this may be underlying issue

Comment: Nannou depends on [wgpu](https://github.com/gfx-rs/wgpu) and currently wgpu only supports Vulkan backend on Linux (although OpenGL support is in progress). I'm sure once you figure out how to enable Vulkan the problem above will resolve itself, as for enabling Vulkan you should probably forward your question to [superuser](https://superuser.com/) since as-is this question isn't appropriate for stackoverflow.

Comment: @preztelhammer, ok thank you! I've asked a new question here https://superuser.com/questions/1612631/vulkan-tools-fails-to-initialize-on-debian-buster-with-nvidia-graphics-card

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that I was using the open-source Nouveau driver for my graphics card (the default on Debian) which does not currently support Vulkan, which is required for Nannou.

By installing the proprietary nvidia graphics driver, the problem was resolved.

I was able to install the nvidia driver by running
`apt install nvidia-driver`,
and then rebooting my computer,
as described in this tutorial https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-nvidia-driver-on-debian-10-buster-linux

Now nannou works :)